# NestJS taking too long to compile and hot-reload not working

Tags: nestjs, compile-time, hot-reload

I just made a project with `nest new new-project` but the compilation takes more than 20 minutes.

Also the hot-reload does not detect any file changes and does not reload when I save the file.

I have implemented this - https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/hot-reload but did not work.

this is what my tsconfig.json file looks like :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  }
}
```

Any pointers is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it it tries to recompile all your `node_modules`.

Please, add this line to your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Alternatively, you can include files you want to compile with this line:

```
{
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

For more info you can refer to [TypeScript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)